# ActiveAdmin specify filter form url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using active-admin(AA, 1.0.0) in a rails 4.2 app. I am displaying a list of online users. I have to display a list of users with scopes for each type of user and filters as per the User model fields. Also, I need to display a list of online users on another page.

```
User(dropdown)
=> Accounts
=> Online Users
```

To display the users list, i have

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'User' do                                                                                                                       
  menu :parent => "Users", :label => "Accounts"
  ...
end
```

To display the online users list, i have

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'Online User' do                                                                                                                
  menu parent: "Users", label: "Online Users", url: '/admin/online_users'
  actions :index

  filter :id
  filter :name
  filter :email
  ...
end
```

Now,the filters are getting displayed properly on the "Online Users" page, but when the filter form is submitted, its submitted to "/admin/users" rather than to "/admin/online_users". Can I pass the url to the filter form? If not, what is the right solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `collection_path` method which is used by the filter form builder like this:

```
controller do
  def collection_path
    admin_online_users_path
  end
end
```